# Xpages Starter Kit Server.jss

Tags: xpages, global

I have a lot of SSJS codes on many NSF, most of the NSF use the same functions code. 
So I tried to make a Library with all the common functions, I'm trying to use the Xpages Starter Kit, because it claims to have SSJS Library Provider and implicit global SSJS.

There theres a Server.jss file that says "//your SSJS library code goes here".

I put some simple code there just to test it, but I couldn't figure out how it works.

```
print("Hello World");
function hello(){
   print("hello");
}
```

How it works?

I made and install the update site, put the `<openntf:canvas/>` on a xpage. The canvas tag is created, but nothing seems to happen with the SSJS. Nothing on server console, and if a try to call hello function an error is raised.

How can I access SSJS functions on the library?

Comment: Did you declare the dependency on your Extlib ?

Comment: Where should I declare? On the library or in the nsf where I am using the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library id - org.openntf.xsp.starter - is defined various places in the Starter Kit. It's also there with "/" instead of "." for some contexts.

Also, double-check the library has been enabled in Xsp Properties for your application.

It's also worth looking at the Domino Debug Plugin on OpenNTF to debug your code directly in Eclipse. Also check the Help > Support > Trace and Help > Support > Log in Domino Designer for any errors for your class.

Comment: The library is still original, I didnt any change on it, except on Server.jss.
The library is enabled in Xsp Properties on my application. 
The library is working, because I can call the canvas control from it.

The thing I didnt figure out how it works is the Server.jss. How to use the functions in there.

Comment: Is there a way to load SSJS before the page load event and it be enabled to all pages?

Im trying to edit the createView on the ViewHandler class. It loads the SSJS library, but it only runs after the before page loaded.

Comment: Jesse Gallagher tried injecting Java into the beforePageLoad event from a ViewHandler, but couldn't. I'm not sure you can load an SSJS library from there. It needs to be allocated as a resource to e.g. the XPage's view component. But the createView is where that view component is loaded, along with all children. At the same time, any code with a page load binding ("${...}") gets run. So if you want to use the SSJS library in page load bindings, I don't think you'll be able to load it before you need it.

Comment: I understood.

Do you suggest a way to do it so? To have a SSJS plugin library that can be accessible in all application?

Comment: A RequestCustomizerFactory was suggested to me as a way to load the SSJS library to the page. I've not used one and I'm not certain whether it gets loaded before the beforePageLoad event runs.